# What is a good example Dynamic Data application?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I'm giving a demonstration of Dynamic Data to a bunch of geeks in two weeks time.  I'm looking for a simpe, but comprehensive data model to build the application on.  I basically just want to register the model and demonstrate the application, as built (scaffolded) without any customisation, to start with, demonstrating list and detail/edit/insert views, and how table relations are handled.

I'd like to avoid one of the standards, i.e. the Customer->Order-OrderItem models, and try something that would be of interest to geeks.  Maybe a Srum project tracker, an or a bug tracker, something like that.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: And those _are_ interesting to geeks?

Comment: @Oded, I have a strong suspicion that the Scrum methodology and bug tracking *are* interesting to geeks, or are you refering to anything else by *those*?

Comment: Nope, nothing else. I just think you and I have different notions on what is _really_ interesting :)

Comment: What would be really interesting is using a namespace as a data model, and types, members, attributes and parameters as related tables, and using Dynamic Data to actually create CLR data types, but my model-to-application part is to be only 2 to 3 minutes long.

Comment: Duplicate at http://forums.asp.net/t/1593127.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take some of your own projects at work, well the database, that you think will be of interest to your audience and use that.

Another application of which I know that it uses Dynamic Data is this one: http://tailspintravel.codeplex.com/. It also integrates into an MVC application so you could show to them that both DD and MVC can work together in the same project.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good.  One of the items on my agenda is the convergence or intersection of DD and MVC.

Comment: Yikes, @XIII, TailspinTravel requires VS2008 as an install pre-requisite.  It will have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: I got : Page not found error please paste alternate link - thanks

Comment: Seems the project's not on codeplex anymore when I search for it.